# Sidebar menu not collapse/hide - bootstrap SB admin 2 (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm now following instructions on [this page](https://github.com/dreamingechoes/bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2).

I copied and imported everything needed and got the following result:

[image]

The menu should be hidden and show when clicked, but it's not.

Link to [my project in GitHub](http://github.com/star747jet/sbadmin2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `gem 'bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2'` to your Gemfile, and run `bundle install`.

And then you have to remove unnecessary files such as `bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2.js` and `jquery` folder from your `assets/javascripts` folder. This is because you have already included `jquery` and `bootstrap_sb_admin_base_v2` in your `application.js`